# Find the scalars though we have ZERO's on the right hand side of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

It seems very weird as the right-hand side values of C1, C2, and C3 are ZERO's. How it can be solved. I am not sure may be it's tricky. Thank you in advance for your help.

\begin{align}
         \\c1\left(1,2,0\right)+c2\left(2,1,1\right)+c3\left(0,3,1\right)=\left(0,0,0\right)
\end{align}

My solution is as follows:

\begin{align}
         \\C_1\:+\:2C_2\:=\:0\:
         \\2C_1\:+\:C_2\:+\:\:C_3\:=\:0\:
         \\ 3C_2\:+\:\:C_3\:=\:0\:
\end{align}

The next step is to multiply eq1 by 2 and subtracts it from the 2nd eq. which results as follows:

\begin{align}
         \\C_3\:=\:0\:
\end{align}

Then I put C3 value in the 3rd equation which results as follows:

\begin{align}
         \\C_2\:=\:0\:
\end{align}

Finally, I put C2 and C3 values in 2nd Eq. to get C1 as follows:

\begin{align}
         \\C_1\:=\:0\:
\end{align}

So scalar value of C1, C2, and C3 is ZERO.

Is this the right solution?

Comment: You can start with $c1+2c2=0$ and proceed.

Comment: This is basically solving the linear system $c_1 + 2c_2 = 0; 2c_1 + c_2 + 3c_3 = 0; c_2 + c_3 = 0$. Can you proceed?

Comment: @Deepak I am up to this step but can't get any scalar value of any c1, c2, or c3 to put into rest equations.

Comment: @LeanLearner As I mentioned in my comment below, you should show your exact working, then people can look for errors.

Comment: Note that $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$ is a completely valid solution, and should not be considered an error.

Comment: @Deepak Can you see the way I did? I was confused because all were zeros.

Comment: @LeanLearner Your second equation is incorrecttly written. Better fix it and recheck your algebra (all steps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite an usual problem in introductory linear algebra. All you have to do is note that

$$ c_1(1,2,0) + c_2(2,1,1) + c_3(0,3,1) = (c_1 + 2c_2, 2c_1 + c_2 + 3c_3, c_2 + c_3).$$

Now, can you determine values for $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that
$$(c_1 + 2c_2, 2c_1 + c_2 + 3c_3, c_2 + c_3)  = (0,0,0) \quad ?$$
It's pretty easy to do such thing: create a system of $3$ equations based on the definition of equal vectors in $\mathbb R^3:$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
c_1+2c_2 = 0 \\
2c_1+c_2+3c_3 = 0 \\
c_2 + c_3 = 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Solving this will yield your answer. I leave these last calculations to you.

**UPDATE.**

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
c_1+2c_2 = 0 \\
2c_1+c_2+3c_3 = 0 \\
c_2 + c_3 = 0
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
c_3 = 0 \\
c_1= -c_3 = 0 \\
c_2 = -c_3 = 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Comment: I went up to this step already. But All I get is zero due to right hand side value zero

Comment: @LeanLearner From this point, you should show your working. You can edit the original question.

Comment: It would be a great help if you could guide me to extract any of the values like c1, c2, or c3. The rest I can do for sure. @Deepak

Comment: @LeanLearner I added the solution of the system to my answer. In fact, the only possible values for $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are $0$. This means that the set $\{ (1,2,0), (2,1,1), (0,3,1) \}$ is linearly independent (the fact that the solution is all zeros isn't an error!)

Comment: @Rodrigo Thank you, I have updated my question can you I got it right?

Comment: @LeanLearner Your second equation is wrongly-written. It's easier to solver this system without multiplying equations by others. From the last line, you directly get that $c_2 = -c_3$, then just replace $c_2$ by $-c_3$ in the second equation and so on...